# Is there a way to restrict string manipulation e.g substring?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

The problem is that I'm processing some UTF8 strings and I would like to design a class or a way to prevent string manipulations.

String manipulation is not desirable for strings of multibyte characters as splitting the string at a random position (which is measured in bytes) may split a character half way.

I have thought about using `const std::string&` but the user/developer can create a substring by calling `std::substr`.

Another way would be create a wrapper around `const std::string&` and expose only the string through getters.

Is this even possible?

Comment: If you are working with Unicode I recommend ditching `std::string` and use [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/) for your string handling.

Comment: In a UTF-8 string, it is very easy to detect when a given string index is in the middle of a multi-byte character. I would simply allow manipulations as needed, and just raise an exception if an invalid index is used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau what about composite characters ie multiple glyphs combining to make 1 character ?  Splitting at the glyph boundary would change the information/meaning.

Comment: I see it as a common pattern that posters are asking for what essentially is a wrapper around a class, expect for some method overrides. Anyone fancy having a generic (perhaps parser-based) solution for it?

Comment: @RichardCritten UTF-8 is such that you can re-sync with the byte stream to char position at the start of next char. That said, the issue is a valid one.

Comment: @thd  Have a read of [Ready-made versus composite characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Ready-made_versus_composite_characters) to realise why just restricting the operations on a `std::string` type class is never going to work.

Comment: The usual way is to wrap a `std::string` (or `std::wstring`, or whatever is appropriate) in another class.   The wrapper class will provide whatever set of operations is considered relevant, but will not expose the contained string (e.g. the string will be `private`, and not offer setters/getters to obtain a reference/pointer to the contained string).   There are work-arounds to that but, as Bjarne Stroustrup has said, C++ access control is designed to protect against Murphy, not against Machiavelli.

Answer (score 2):

> Another way would be create a wrapper around const std::string& and expose only the string through getters.

You need a class wrapping a `std::string` or `std::u8string`, not a reference to one. The class then owns the string and its contents, basically just using it as a storage, and can provide an interface as you see fit to operate on unicode code points or characters instead of modifying the storage directly.

However, there is nothing in the standard library that will help you implement this. So a better approach would be to use a third party library that already does this for you. Operating on code points in a UTF-8 string is still reasonably simple and you can implement that part yourself, but if you want to operate on characters (in the sense of grapheme clusters or whatever else is suitable) implementation is going to be a project in itself.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a wrapper where your external interface provides access to either code points, or to characters. So, `foo.substr(3, 4)` (for example) would skip the first 3 code points, and give you the next 4 code points. Alternatively, it would skip the first 3 characters, and give you the next 4 characters.

Either way, that would be independent of the number of bytes used to represent those code points or characters.

Quick aside on terminology for anybody unaccustomed to Unicode terminology: ISO 10646 is basically a long list of code points, each assigned a name and a number from 0 to (about) 2<sup>20</sup>-1. UTF-8 encodes a code point number in a sequence of 1 to 4 bytes.

A character can consist of a (more or less) arbitrary number of code points. It will consist of a base character (e.g., a letter) followed by some number of combining diacritical marks. For example, `à` would normally be encoded as an `a` followed by a "combining grave accent" (U+0300).

The `a` and the U+0300 are each a code point. When encoded in UTF-8, the `a` would be encoded in a single byte and the U+0300 would be encoded in three bytes. So, it's one character composed of two code points encoded in 4 characters.

That's not quite all there is to characters (as opposed to code points) but it's sufficient for quite a few languages (especially, for the typical European languages like Spanish, German, French, and so on).

There are a fair number of other points that become non-trivial though. For example, German has a letter "ß". This is one character, but when you're doing string comparison, it should (at least normally) compare as equal to "ss". I believe there's been a move to change this but at least classically, it hasn't had an upper-case equivalent either, so both comparison and case conversion with it get just a little bit tricky.

And that's fairly mild compared to situations that arise in some of the more "exotic" languages. But it gives a general idea of the fact that yes, if you want to deal intelligently with Unicode strings, you basically have two choices: either have your code use ICU<sup>1</sup> to do most of the real work, or else resign yourself to this being a multi-year project in itself.

---

<sup>1. In theory, you could use another suitable library--but in this case, I'm not aware of such a thing existing.</sup>